# Any way to improve the performance of this store procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-execution-plan, query-performance

Any way to improve the performance of this store procedure?
For example combining both updates clauses in a unique statement (T-SQL).
BonosConvenio and CON_Convenio are almost 5K rows.

```
create table #resultados (
        monto_deuda      float
       ,Cuenta           float
       ,Rut              varchar(10)
       ,CodCONVENIO      varchar(4)
       ,CONVENIO         varchar(50)
       ,Bono             varchar(15)
       ,MontoBono        float
       ,ApellDeudor      varchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO #resultados(Cuenta,monto_deuda,Rut,CodCONVENIO,CONVENIO,Bono,MontoBono,ApellDeudor) 
select ATC_CTA_Correlativo, monto_deuda, RutDeudor, CodCONVENIO,'','',0,''
    from CartaCobProgramasCONVENIO
    where Nomina = @Nomina

UPDATE #resultados 
SET Bono=bc.Bono,
    MontoBono=bc.Monto
FROM BonosCONVENIO bc
WHERE bc.ATC_CTA_Correlativo=#resultados.Cuenta;

UPDATE #resultados 
SET ApellDeudor=upper(rtrim(ltrim(Paciente.PAC_PAC_Nombre)) 
FROM BD_ENTI_CORPORATIVA..ATC_Cuenta Cuenta, BD_ENTI_CORPORATIVA..PAC_Paciente Paciente
WHERE Cuenta.ATC_CTA_Correlativo=#resultados.Cuenta AND Paciente.PAC_PAC_Numero = Cuenta.PAC_PAC_Numero

UPDATE #resultados 
SET CONVENIO=c.CON_CON_Descripcio
FROM BD_ENTI_CORPORATIVA..CON_Convenio c
WHERE c.CON_CON_Codigo =#resultados.CodCONVENIO

SELECT * FROM #resultados ORDER BY Cuenta,Bono
End
```

Comment: Yes, do some joins and do a single select statement - no need for the temp table and updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  ccpc.ATC_CTA_Correlativo                     Cuenta
, ccpc.monto_deuda
, ccpc.RutDeudor                               Rut
, ccpc.CodCONVENIO
, c.CON_CON_Descripcio                         CONVENIO
, bc.Bono
, bc.Monto                                     MontoBono
, UPPER(RTRIM(LTRIM(Paciente.PAC_PAC_Nombre))) ApellDeudor

FROM
  CartaCobProgramasCONVENIO ccpc
    INNER JOIN
    BonosCONVENIO bc ON
  ccpc.ATC_CTA_Correlativo = bc.ATC_CTA_Correlativo
    INNER JOIN
    BD_ENTI_CORPORATIVA..ATC_Cuenta Cuenta ON
  ccpc.ATC_CTA_Correlativo = Cuenta.ATC_CTA_Correlativo
    INNER JOIN
    BD_ENTI_CORPORATIVA..PAC_Paciente Paciente ON
  Cuenta.PAC_PAC_Numero = Paciente.PAC_PAC_Numero
    INNER JOIN
    BD_ENTI_CORPORATIVA..CON_Convenio c ON
  c.CON_CON_Codigo = ccpc.CodCONVENIO
WHERE Nomina = @Nomina;
```

If you have duplicate records because of the joins, it's because there are multiple values in the tables.  Your original query (using an update) would overwrite and only show the last row's value. To work around this, you would probably want to have a `GROUP BY` and `MIN`, `MAX`, `SUM` or whatever.